# XML validation error when updating Keyword metadata

Tags: tridion

Following on from my earlier question about creating Address Books (many thanks Peter!), I have a small throw-away console application doing just that and working great - but in addition I'm trying to update the metadata of a Keyword with the Item Id of the created Address Book.

Slightly shortened snippet ...

```
StaticAddressBook ab = new StaticAddressBook();
ab.Title = title;
ab.Key = key;
ab.Save();

// id is a correct Keyword TCM ID
Keyword k = tdse.GetObject(id, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeEdit);
if (k != null)
{
    k.MetadataFields["addressbookid"].value[0] = ab.Id.ItemId;
    k.Save(true);
}
```

I keep getting the following error on Save():

> XML validation error. Reason: The element 'Metadata' in namespace
>   'uuid:2065d525-a365-4b45-b68e-bf45f0fba188' has invalid child element
>   'addressbookid' in namespace
>   'uuid:2065d525-a365-4b45-b68e-bf45f0fba188'. List of possible elements
>   expected: 'contact_us_email' in namespace
>   'uuid:2065d525-a365-4b45-b68e-bf45f0fba188'

But I know the Keyword has the correct Metadata assigned, (thats why I don't bother checking!). Shortened Tridion XML from a current keyword in question:

```
<tcm:Keyword>
   <tcm:Data>
      <tcm:MetadataSchemaxlink:type="simple"xlink:title="IP.Location.Metadata" xlink:href="tcm:49-2142-8" />
      <tcm:Metadata>
         <Metadata xmlns="uuid:2065d525-a365-4b45-b68e-bf45f0fba188">
            <email>...</email>
            <addressbookid>3</addressbookid>
            <contact_us_email>...</contact_us_email>
            <request_a_sample_email>...</request_a_sample_email>
            <webinar_feedback_email>....</webinar_feedback_email>
         </Metadata>
      </tcm:Metadata>
      <tcm:IsRoot>true</tcm:IsRoot>
   </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Keyword>
```

Have I missed something can Keyword metadata not be updated in this way?

I guess I could look at the Core Service to update Keywords, but it seemed to to make sense to do everything within this application.

**UPDATE**

Order was key here, strangely!
The following code works:

```
ItemFields fields = k.MetadataFields;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fields.Count);

string email = fields[1].value[1];
string contact = fields[3].value[1];
string request = fields[4].value[1];
string webinar = fields[5].value[1];

fields[1].value[1] = email;
fields[2].value[1] = ab.Id.ItemId;
fields[3].value[1] = contact;
fields[4].value[1] = request;
fields[5].value[1] = webinar;

k.Save(true);
```

Got caught out by the non-0-based index when getting/setting values and had to reassign existing fields back, in order.

Cheers

Comment: Almost replied with "Use ItemFields, it will handle that for you"... then noticed you're using TDSE... Try opening/saving & closing the keyword, then try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the order of the fields has changed in the Schema since that Component was created. At least the Schema expects `contact_us_email` in the position where you current have `addressbookid`.

There may be other changes, so I'd verify the order of fields in the Schema and make sure the Component(s) match, before you run your tool.

Comment: From the XML he posted I read that the field already exists with a value - so it would just overwrite that value. It wouldn't automatically fix the order.